# Adding a factor legend to a scatterplot matrix in R?

Tags: r, graphics, data-visualization, legend, scatter-plot

I have made a scatterplot matrix which is conditioned on two factors, one with different colours and one with different shapes. I want to add a legend to the right-middle of the plot showing the labels for just the factor with the shapes (Scenario), is this possible? I have looked online but cannot figure it out! Here is my code, I would be grateful for any help. Thank you.

```
pairs(Data[,1:3], col=Data$Physician, pch=Data$Scenario, main="Scatterplot Matrix")
```

Comment: use the `oma` parameter in your `pairs` call to add a bit of space to the right of the plot. then use `legend` to add the legend to where you added the extra space: use `xpd=NA` within the legend to suppress the clipping.

Comment: Explore the par() function. It offers a lot of control over the plotting area. Also look at the lattice package.